# Save data from table rows in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I have multiple input fields with same name in a page when i try to save i throws an error.how should i save data from multiple table row data into database.
the error
Creating default object from empty value at 
here $varientaccesss->variant_id = $request->input('varient'),

[image: Page i designed]

Controller

```
public function storevarient_update(Request $request)
    {
//return $request;
        $varientprice = new Price();
        $varientprice->variant_id = $request->input('varient');
        $varientprice->discount = $request->input('discount');
        $varientprice->price = $request->input('vehicleprice');
        $varientprice->save();


        $varientaccess = new Categoryvariantmapping();

          foreach ($varientaccess as $varientaccesss){

        $varientaccesss->variant_id = $request->input('varient');
        $varientaccesss->cat_id = $request->input('test');
        $varientaccesss->rate = $request->input('cat_price');
        $varientaccesss->status = '0';

       $varientaccess->save();
   }

        return redirect('Varientupdate')->with('success', 'Details  Added Successfully');


    }
```

dd($request->all);

[image]

Comment: put `$varientaccess = new Categoryvariantmapping();` and `$varientaccess->save();` inside foreach it will only save once because you initialize it outside the loop

Comment: i don't quite understand that.. i try to include the save() but doesn't work @Beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can save like this

```
public function storevarient_update(Request $request)
{
    //return $request;
    $varientprice = new Price();
    $varientprice->variant_id = $request->input('varient');
    $varientprice->discount = $request->input('discount');
    $varientprice->price = $request->input('vehicleprice');
    $varientprice->save();
    $cat_id = $request->input('cat_price');
    $test_ids = $request->input('test');
    foreach($test_ids as $key => $test)
    {
        $varientaccesss = new Categoryvariantmapping();
        $varientaccesss = new Categoryvariantmapping();
        $varientaccesss->variant_id = $request->input('varient'),
        $varientaccesss->cat_id = $test,
        $varientaccesss->rate = $cat_id[$key],
        $varientaccesss->status = '0',
        $varientaccess->save();
    }
    return redirect('Varientupdate')->with('success', 'Details  Added Successfully');
}
```

Comment: i have done this but only one data from the table row is stored in the database that's why i try to loop it.i need to store the data from the table row correspond to varient  @Shaielndra Gupta

Comment: can you share `dd($request->all())` screen shot

Comment: i updated in the question check it.screen shot of my dd @Shaielndra Gupta

Comment: Let me try it @Shaielndra Gupta

Comment: Boom it worked,thank you very much... @Shaielndra Gupta

Answer (score -1):

The purpose of this is to initialize a new data which you are going to save in the database soon

```
$varientaccess = new Categoryvariantmapping();
```

but you put it outside the loop

```
$varientaccess = new Categoryvariantmapping();

foreach(....)
```

which mean no matter how many rows inside foreach it will only save once because you it won't initialize again

so the solution is to put it inside loop

```
foreach(....) {

    $varientaccess = new Categoryvariantmapping();
    $varientaccesss->variant_id = $request->input('varient');
    $varientaccesss->cat_id = $request->input('test');
    $varientaccesss->rate = $request->input('cat_price');
    $varientaccesss->status = '0';

   $varientaccess->save();

}
```

Comment: try putting an `if ($varientaccess->save()) { echo 'success'; }` to determine if the other data successfully save

Comment: I have got it @Beginner